# Bluetooth, TBluetooth component in delphi android app

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, android-bluetooth, delphi-xe5, adafruit

I have to write a mobile app using Delphi. The app needs to receive information and data from an [Adafruit Feather](https://www.adafruit.com/feather) via Bluetooth. I use Delphi XE5.

How would you do this in Delphi XE5?

Comment: XE5 is first version that supported Android. In the meantime there were 4 new releases. It is fairly possible that by now XE5 is too old to do Android development with it without bumping into numerous issues. As far as examples are concerned start with Delphi documentation.

Answer (score 2):

RAD Studio XE7 is the first version that added native Bluetooth support to the RTL.

[RTL API for Bluetooth and Classic Bluetooth Support for App Tethering](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE7#RTL_API_for_Bluetooth_and_Classic_Bluetooth_Support_for_App_Tethering)

[Using Bluetooth](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Using_Bluetooth)

For earlier versions, you will have to use JNI to access the [Android Java APIs for Bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html).

You can't write effective Android apps in Delphi without *some* interactions with Java, so you are best off learning how to do it.